# ion-grid with alternate columns

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I'm not very familiar with Angular. I would like to have a grid like this:

[image]

i.e. have one image per row alternating with two images.I tried with this code but I get a slightly different grid (I also get the same image twice because I don't know how to increase the index inside the loop):

.html:

```
<ion-content>

  <ion-grid class="design">
    <ion-row size="12" *ngFor="let t of types ; let i=index">
      <ion-col *ngIf="i%3==0" size="12">
        <img oncontextmenu="return false;" src={{t?.img}} class="center" />
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col *ngIf="i%3!=0" size="6">
        <img oncontextmenu="return false;" src={{t?.img}} class="center" />
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col *ngIf="i%3!=0" size="6">
        <img oncontextmenu="return false;" src={{types[i+1]?.img}} class="center"/>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

</ion-content>
```

.scss:

```
.design {
  position: center;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

How could I modify it ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jB_h4_pwxg0&t=1s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap rows in `ion-row` element and everything in the `ion-grid`, then you can use `ion-col` for each column. Here is the simple example of full-width element and 2-column row: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-yxpfht?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

You may also refer to the [official docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/grid) since there is a nice example as well of how to use grid. Additionally, you may want to manipulate spacing/gutter, which is explained in the docs.

And if you have your images in array, like this `['img1', 'img2', 'img3'] you may want to check if you have 3 to display them 2 + 1 (2 in the first row and 1 in the second), so then you can just use something like on the stackblitz example.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But your solution is for a static grid. My list 'types' can increase and decrease, so I can't define rows statically

Comment: I've updated the solution. As you may see on the stackblitz, you loop over all items but you use modulo to display them in the proper way.

Comment: ok thank you. It's work. I added an additional ion-row with ngIf in case the rest is 1 and it is the last element of the list